# Alter CSS with no unique class name or ID

Tags: html, css

I am trying to alter the css on a `div` that doesn't have a unique class name or id and don't have the ability to give it an id as it is part of a library. This is the layout of the item I am trying to alter.

I am wanting to add some CSS to `<div class='thirdClass' />`. Can you use `nth-of-type`? I couldn't get that to work.

```
<button id='myUsefulBtn'>
  <div class='firstClass' />
  <div class='secondClass' />
  <div class='thirdClass' />
</button>
```

I was able to get it working with this. Not sure if there is a better way though...

```
#myUsefulBtn div:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Nope, if you can't use a distinct class then nth-of-type or nth-child is your only option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, to target `<div class='thirdClass' />` **without a unique class or ID**, you can use `nth-child` as valid approach **if the structure remains consistent**. Meaning, it is the best way if this is the case.

```css
#myUsefulBtn div:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Even if the class is not unique within the file, as long as it is unique within the siblings, you could still use it to select the div, since the parent has a unique ID. And looking at the provided HTML, none of the other siblings have the `thirdClass` class.